# Prove that $E_{\alpha} \setminus \bigcup\limits_{\beta \neq \alpha} E_{\beta} \neq \varnothing,$ for all $\alpha \in I.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\Lambda = \left \{E_{\alpha}\ |\ \alpha \in I \right \}$ be an uncountable family of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ such that intersection of any two subsets in $\Lambda$ has a finite intersection. Show that $E_{\alpha} \setminus \bigcup\limits_{\beta \neq \alpha} E_{\beta} \neq \varnothing,$ for any $\alpha \in I.$

If possible let there be an $\alpha \in I$ such that $E_{\alpha} \setminus \bigcup\limits_{\beta \neq \alpha} E_{\beta} = \varnothing$ i.e. $E_{\alpha} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\beta \neq \alpha} E_{\beta}.$ That means there is a countable subset $J$ of $I \setminus \left \{\alpha \right \}$ such that $E_{\alpha} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\beta \in J} E_{\beta}.$ From here how do I arrive at a contradiction? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is not true.

Let $I_0,I_1$ be two disjoint subsets of $I$ such that $|I_0|=|I_1|=\aleph_0$, so we can write them as $\alpha_n^0$ and $\alpha_n^1$ for the $n$th set in $I_0$ and $I_1$ respectively. Now redefine your family:

1. If $\alpha\notin I_0\cup I_1$, $E_\alpha$ stays the same.
2. If $\alpha=\alpha_n^i$ for either $i\in\{0,1\}$, $E_\alpha$ is replaced by $E_\alpha\cup\{n\}$.

It is now easy to see that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I_0}E_\alpha=\Bbb N$, and the same for $I_1$. So if $\alpha\in I$, then either $\alpha\notin I_0$ or $\alpha\notin I_1$. But in either case, $\bigcup_{\beta\neq\alpha}E_\beta=\Bbb N$, so $E_\alpha\setminus\bigcup_{\beta\neq\alpha}E_\beta=\varnothing$.